# How to assign different default values to the column while creating migration file

Tags: c#, migration, entity-framework-5

I want to assign the value of an existing column as a default value to the newly added column.

In the Migration file there is:

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.Table1", "SecondName", c => c.String());
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropColumn("dbo.Table1", "SecondName");
    }
```

In this table there is also "FirstName" column.

How can I assign the values of "FirstName" column to "SecondName" column as a default value?

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply renaming a column `RenameColumn` should work for you.

If not you can use the `SQL` method to update the column values.
There isn't a built in way to see data motion in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx).